# Curve Modifier Problem

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I have a mesh which want to array 360 degrees with help of curve modifier and array modifier. I created a circle curve. I moved cursor to its origion and mesh's origin to cursor. I want to array it on y axis but when i click on it, it turns my mesh upside down under where it is not supposed to be. When i drag it on x axis, it moves on z axis. i tried CRTL+A - scale, rotarion, too in case. But still same.

Above, position of my mesh and curve

[image]

[image]

[image]

The result

[image]

[image]

Comment: Im not getting you said array in 360 and In y axis what u mean and can u sketch diagram and let us know what you want need

Comment: y axis of the object or of the curve modifier ?

Comment: i mean arraying that msh on that circle by using array and curve tools. So it happens with y axis on curve tool. But it rotates the mesh and put it below. I added the file to the post above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not really sure what exactly  what you exactly mean by "array it on y axis" but my answer is based on "360 degrees". You could try uploading your [Blend](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) in the question to get a proper answer. But here's what i got.

[image]

Here's the blend file:-
[image]

## Edit:---------------------------------

So i looked into your blend and it seems like you must've turned off the **Modifier visilibilty** of the array modifier. Also you need to use the x axis in both of the modifiers and rotate the object in edit mode in order to achieve similar results like mine (if thats your goal).
[image]

Comment: Where you get the blend from him. He never attach the file

Comment: this is not his blend. i made some assumptions and recreated it.

Comment: That is what i am trying to do but i don't know what i do wrong with mine. i added the file on the post above.

Comment: i edited the answer.

Comment: I made array modifier invisible to see where single mesh stands. I am trying to achieve this shape with my mesh. https://prnt.sc/h3fqqv

Comment: look into my blend file and see what i did, the first gif should answer your question, if it did please accept the answer, if not im sure any one else can help you.

Comment: Ah i just saw the solution in first gif after checking it again. Sorry, it has the answer. So what i had to do was to use x axis by rotating it in edit mode. I was trying to solve it by usin y axis. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -2):

If i understood your question

1. The curve axis is to x axis and not to Y axis. So change from Y to X axis
2. In the array in the relative set the x to 1 and rest to zero

And unhide the array modifier

This will give the result

[image]

Comment: No no, i mean y axis of the curve modifier . My aim is to make this shape (https://prnt.sc/h3fqqv) by using curve and array modifier.